# What does algebraic in algebraic data types mean in functional languages?

Tags: functional-programming, pattern-matching, algebraic-data-types

I'm just starting to learn about functional programming and one of the things that I still don't get is the adjective "algebraic" in the expression algebraic data types.

Reading the first few sections of the Wikipedia article on the subject, I see that linked lists are one example of such ADT.  Another example that is given are trees and, to be honest, I can't see much more algebra in them than I can see in a "vanilla" hierarchy of classes like toy examples like the familiar Animal class with, say, a subclass Cat and another one being Dog. I can, for instance, pattern match on all these types with, say, Scala.

So, what is the secret sauce that I am certainly missing here?

Comment: `ADT` stands for **Abstract** Data Type, not **Algebraic** Data Type.

Comment: Hmm, it seems that I may be wrong. In FP, ADT does indeed stand for Algebraic.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it would be more appropriate for cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Barmar, I would definitely love to see non-technical non-technical explanations to this question. I feel that it is elementary for people who program in functional languages.

Comment: Basically, I think it means that new types are built up from simpler types using algebra similar to set theory.

Comment: E.g. `NewType = OldType1 | OldType2`, which corresponds to the set `UNION` operator.

Comment: So, any composite type would be algebraic?

Comment: _composite type_ usually refers to types that group elements, e.g. structures and arrays. Algebraic types allow for other types of composition, like the OR operator in my previous example.

Comment: E.g. a linked list is either `NULL` (representing an empty list) **OR** a composite type containing an element (the _head_) and another linked list (the _rest_ of the list)

Comment: And or would be expressed, say, via inheritance, like my example of the Animal Animal class?

Comment: It's bedtime here. I will come back after I wake up.

Comment: No, this is different from inheritance. In OOP, you start with a base class, and then refine and extend it with subclasses. In ADT, you start with primitive types, and combine them into more complex types.

Comment: Please write an answer and I may select it once I digest the nuances.

Comment: I'd prefer it if someone with real experience in FP would write a more precise answer.

Comment: In short, it's because you can define an algebra *over types* instead of mere numbers - hence the terms "sum type" and "product type", those really are addition and multiplication of types (and functions are exponentiation). Check out [the second half of the first answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190352/abusing-the-algebra-of-algebraic-data-types-why-does-this-work) and [this blog post](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/01/haskell-for-mainstream-programmers.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing definition of 'algebraic data type' in the book "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22114230/missing-definition-of-algebraic-data-type-in-the-book-learn-you-a-haskell-for)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why "Algebraic data type" use "Algebraic" in the name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061345/why-algebraic-data-type-use-algebraic-in-the-name)

Comment: read everything in http://stackoverflow.com/q/9190352/2007884 along with possible further links in the description - including the question itself. That should answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

I have answered this question before<sup>[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22114230/783743)</sup>. Nevertheless, I'll briefly reiterate why we describe data types as being "algebraic" in this answer.

First, let's understand what the word "algebra" means. The word "algebra" is derived from the Arabic phrase "al-jabr" which means "reunion of broken parts"<sup>[[2]](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=algebra)</sup>. The theme of breaking down problems into simpler problems (decomposition) and then reintegrating the solutions to these problems into the final solution (recomposition) is central to several fields including programming<sup>[[3]](http://worrydream.com/LearnableProgramming/)</sup>.

The phrase "al-jabr" was a part of the title of a famous paper on equations<sup>[[4]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Compendious_Book_on_Calculation_by_Completion_and_Balancing)</sup> written by the Persian mathematician Muhammad al-Khwarizmi, better known as Algoritmi in Latin. The word "algorithm" was derived from his name. The title of the paper was "Kitab al-Jabr w'al-Muqabala" which translates to "Rules of Reintegration and Reduction". It was this paper that introduced Arabic numerals to the West.

Algebra is all about reintegration (i.e. combining parts of an object into the whole). Hence, algebraic data types are about combining simpler data types into more complex data types. You can think of a data type as a set. For example, the data type `Int` is the set of all integers. We can combine simpler types into more complex types using the cartesian product operation and the disjoint union operation.

The cartesian product operation produces product types<sup>[[5]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_type)</sup>. For example, if we have two data types, `Int` and `Char`, then the cartesian product `Int × Char` is the set of all the possible pairs of integers and characters. A value of the type `Int × Char` is the pair `(0, 'a')`.

The disjoint union operation produces sum types<sup>[[6]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union)</sup>. For example, if we have two data types, `Int` and `Char`, then the disjoint union `Int + Char` is the set of all integers tagged with `Int` or characters tagged with `Char`. Values of the type `Int + Char` are the pairs `(0, Int)` and `('a', Char)`.

Algebraic data types allow you to define data types algebraically. For example, the following `Shape` data type is a disjoint union of the `Circle` and `Rectangle` types which are both cartesian products of the `Double` type:

```
data Shape = Circle    { x  :: Double, y  :: Double, r  :: Double }
           | Rectangle { x1 :: Double, y1 :: Double, x2 :: Double, y2 :: Double }
```

This is the reason why they are called "algebraic" data types.