# Why "Algebraic data type" use "Algebraic" in the name?

Tags: functional-programming, algebraic-data-types

When I learn Scala/Haskell, I see there is a concept of [Algebraic data type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type). I've read the explanation from the wikipedia, but I still have a question:

Why does it use the word "Algebraic" in its name? Does it have some relationship with "Algebraic"?

Answer (score 4):

In simple words we must consider here relationship between algebra and types. Haskell's algebraic data types are named such since they correspond to an initial algebra in category theory.

Wikipedia says:

> In computer programming, particularly functional programming and type
>   theory, an algebraic data type is a kind of composite type, i.e. a
>   type formed by combining other types.

Let's take `Maybe a` data type:

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

`Maybe a` indicates that it might contain something of type `a` - `Just Int` for example, but also can be empty - `Nothing`. In haskell types are objects, for example `Int`. Operators gets types and produces new types, for example `Maybe Int`. `Algebraic` refers to the property that an Algebraic Data Type is created by `algebraic` operations: `sums` and `product` where:

- "sum" is alternation (A | B, meaning A or B but not both)
- "product" is combination (A B, meaning A and B together)

For example, let's see `sum` for `Maybe a`. For the start let's define `Add` type:

```
data Add a b = Left a | Right b
```

In haskell `|` is `or`, so it can be or `Left a` or `Right b`. Vertical bar `|` shows us that `Maybe` which we defined above is a sum type, it means that we can write it with `Add`:

```
type Maybe a = Add Nothing (Just a)
```

`Nothing` here is here is a `unit` type:

> In the area of mathematical logic and computer science known as type
>   theory, a unit type is a type that **allows** only one value

```
data Unit = Unit
```

Or `()` in haskell.

`Just a` is a singleton type as. Singleton types are those types which have only one value.

```
data Just a = Just a
```

After it we can rewrite it as:

```
type Maybe a = Add () a
```

So we have unit type - `1`, and singleton type which is - `a`. Now we can say that `Maybe a` is the same as 1 + a.

If you want to go deep - [The Algebra of Data, and the Calculus of Mutation](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/3011)

Comment: The link is now dead.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the type `Bool`. This type, of course, can take on one of **two** possible values: True or False.

Now consider

```
data EitherBool = Left Bool | Right Bool
```

How many values can this type take on? There are 4: `Left False, Left True, Right False, Right True`. How about

```
data EitherBoolInt = Left Bool | Right Int8
```

Here there are 2 possible values in the Left branch, and 2^8 in the Right branch. For a total of 2 + 2^8 possible values for `EitherBoolInt`. It should be easy to see that for any set of constructors and types, this kind of construction will give you a datatype with a space of possible values the size of the **sum** of the possible values of each individual constructor. For this reason, it's called a **sum type**.

Consider instead

```
data BoolAndInt = BAndI Bool Int8
```

or simply

```
type BoolAndInt = (Bool, Int)
```

How many values can this take on? For *each* possible Int8, there are two BoolAndInts, for a total of 2*2^8 = 2^9 total values. The total number of possible values is the **product** of the number of values of each field of the constructor, so this is called a **product** type.

This idea can be extended further -- for example, functions from a->b are an **exponential** datatype (see [The Algebra of Algebraic Datatypes](http://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/02/10/the-algebra-of-algebraic-data-types/)). You can even create a reasonable notion of the **derivative** of a datatype. This is not even a purely theoretical idea -- it's the basis for the functional construct of "zippers". See [The Derivative of a Datatype is the Type of its One-Hole Contexts](http://strictlypositive.org/diff.pdf) and [The Wikipedia entry on zippers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper_(data_structure)#Zipper_contexts_and_differentiation).

Comment: I read the whole answer, but still don't know wy algebraic types are called aglebraic.You talk about the cardinality of the image set but why the name is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50375/whats-the-meaning-of-algebraic-data-type

My answer (there): it's all about algebraic theories.